# Replace null value with a string in an array which is a JSON output - V2.0

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, null

I was trying to replace the null value that I get through a JSON after submitting a form by a String value like 'n/a' or 'not specified'. I have added few lines as @Winter Solider suggested which is commented below to check null value and replace it but the code I added doesn't work. And idea?
-thanks

```
function submitFormFunction() {
  //document.getElementById("form").submit();
  var valueArray = [
    {
      'label': 'contractId',
      'value': document.getElementById('ContractId').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'title',
      'value': document.getElementById('ContractTitle').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'minYear',
      'value': document.getElementById('MinYear').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'maxYear',
      'value': document.getElementById('MaxYear').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'terminal',
      'value': document.getElementById('Terminal').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'location',
      'value': document.getElementById('Location').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'theme',
      'value': document.getElementById('Theme').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'construction',
      'value': document.getElementById('Construction').value
    },
    {
      'label': 'asBuilt',
      'value': document.getElementById('AsBuilt').value
    }
  ].map(function (param) { return param.label + '=' + param.value; });
        
  if (valueArray.length) {
    // here I am trying to handle the null value issue as suggested by Winter Soldier 
    for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
      if (valueArray[i].includes("null")) {
        valueArray[i] = valueArray[i].replace("null", "n/a");
      }
    }
  
    console.log(valueArray)
    console.log(valueArray.join('&'));
    //var queryStr = JSON.stringify(valueArray.replacer);
    var queryString = valueArray.join('&');
    fetch(searchUrl, '?' + queryString, function (data) {
      // output search results to the dom
      renderSearchResults(JSON.parse(data), document.getElementById('searchResults'));
    });
  } else {
      document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = "Please enter a search term.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your null values are getting filtered out even before you execute the
  map. Whenever there is a null value from element you are looking up,
  it ends up being filtered out.
- So you are better off not using the filter. Modify your code based on
  other answers. Switch to each or something.
- Though I have 9 inputs, it only prints 8

See the below code

```js
var valueArray = [
  {
    'label': 'contractId',
    'value': 'ContractId'
  },
  {
    'label': 'title',
    'value': 'ContractTitle'
  },
  {
    'label': 'minYear',
    'value': 'MinYear'
  },
  {
    'label': 'maxYear',
    'value': 'MaxYear'
  },
  {
    'label': 'terminal',
    'value': 'Terminal'
  },
  {
    'label': 'location',
    'value': 'Location'
  },
  {
    'label': 'theme',
    'value': 'Theme'
  },
  {
    'label': 'construction',
    'value': 'Construction'
  },
  {
    'label': 'asBuilt',
    'value': null
  }
].filter(function (param) { return param.value; })

console.log(valueArray)
console.log(valueArray.length)
```

EDIT:

- Is this what you need at the end of null check?
- If you are trying to replace the null string value with n/a, this is
  perhaps what you'll need to do
- Edited the code to refelct `""` check

```js
var valueArray = [{
  'label': 'contractId',
  'value': 'ContractId'
}, {
  'label': 'title',
  'value': 'ContractTitle'
}, {
  'label': 'minYear',
  'value': 'MinYear'
}, {
  'label': 'maxYear',
  'value': 'MaxYear'
}, {
  'label': 'terminal',
  'value': 'Terminal'
}, {
  'label': 'location',
  'value': 'Location'
}, {
  'label': 'theme',
  'value': ''
}, {
  'label': 'construction',
  'value': 'Construction'
}, {
  'label': 'asBuilt',
  'value': null
}].map(function(param) {
  return param.label + '=' + param.value;
});
if (valueArray.length) {
  // here I am trying to handle the null value issue
  for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
    if (valueArray[i].includes("null") || !valueArray[i].split("=")[1].length ) {
      valueArray[i] = valueArray[i].split("=")[0] + "=n/a";
    }
  }
  console.log(valueArray)
  console.log(valueArray.join('&'));
  //the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but im confused. if its being filtered how i get still null values when i populate a table with the searchResult output?

Comment: Check if your document.getElementById('XYZ').value is returning a _null_ object or **'null'** string

Comment: how can i check that? ^_^

Comment: By running for example this `document.getElementById('ContractId').value` in developer window's console of your browser

Comment: @alast There you go. Please accept the answer, if it solves your question.

Comment: well it seems working in the code snippet here but not mine :/

Comment: Please post the error message you receive from the UI- developer console window probably along with the changes done to the code. Leave the existing code for reference, edit your question add your code by calling it edit 2.0 something

Comment: i dont get any error msg. my dataset still returns null. i try to post my current code.

Comment: Handled both null & "". Does that fetch you the right queryString?  `if (valueArray[i].includes("null") || !valueArray[i].split("=")[1].length ) {
      valueArray[i] = valueArray[i].split("=")[0] + "=n/a";
    }` Please examine the second snippet of my answer to see it running

Comment: cool.. its working but replacing all the values: contractId=n/a&title=n/a&minYear=n/a&maxYear=n/a&terminal=IH&location=n/a&theme=n/a&construction=n/a&asBuilt=n/a

Comment: Could you add a line `console.log(valueArray)` right before this if statement `if (valueArray.length) {` and paste the result in comments?

Comment: Array[9]0: "contractId=n/a"1: "title=n/a"2: "minYear=n/a"3: "maxYear=n/a"4: "terminal=IH"5: "location=n/a"6: "theme=n/a"7: "construction=n/a"8: "asBuilt=n/a"length: 9__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: No this is after all the processing, I'm asking to log it after you prepare map, look exactly what my above comment is asking for.

Comment: Oops.. :P  i had few more console logs. just removed them all.

Comment: log it after this line `].map(function (param) { return param.label + '=' + param.value; });`

Comment: ].map(function (param) { return param.label + '=' + param.value; });
    console.log(valueArray);
    if (valueArray.length) {

Comment: same: Array[9]0: "contractId=n/a"1: "title=n/a"2: "minYear=n/a"3: "maxYear=n/a"4: "terminal=n/a"5: "location=n/a"6: "theme=n/a"7: "construction=n/a"8: "asBuilt=n/a"length: 9__proto__: Array[0]  --ill be back after lunch :)

Comment: so is `n/a` your actual input from HTML element?

Comment: i guess your for loop made it return n/a now that i changed it back to what it was it returns: Array[9]0: "contractId="1: "title="2: "minYear="3: "maxYear="4: "terminal="5: "location="6: "theme="7: "construction="8: "asBuilt="length: 9__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: I tested my logic with the kind of array you pasted above, it works like charm. Check to see if you are including the logic the way its in my code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

**Observation:** You are using `filter` unnecessarily as it creates another array on `valueArray` array. Instead you can use `forEach`. and

**Solution:**

```
if (valueArray.length) { // It'll do the same job as 'valueArraylength > 0'
    // here I am trying to handle the null value issue
    valueArray.forEach(function(value){
        if (value == null || value == "") {
          value = "n/a";
        }
    })
    //var queryStr = JSON.stringify(valueArray.replacer);
    var queryString = valueArray.join('&');
    fetch(searchUrl, '?' + queryString, function (data) {
        // output search results to the dom
        renderSearchResults(JSON.parse(data), document.getElementById('searchResults'));
    });
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly for me. Perhaps you need to check for the empty string as well?

```js
var valueArray=[5,6,7,8,null,3,4,5,0,0,0,9,''," "]
            for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
                if (valueArray[i] === null || valueArray[i] === ' ' || valueArray[i] === '') {
                    valueArray[i] = 'n/a';
                }
              console.log(valueArray[i]);
            }
```

Comment: I issue was with the filter

Comment: Ah, hope you found a solution :)

Comment: You saved me my weekend! God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var valueArray = [{
  'label': 'contractId',
  'value': 'ContractId'
}, {
  'label': 'title',
  'value': 'ContractTitle'
}, {
  'label': 'minYear',
  'value': 'MinYear'
}, {
  'label': 'maxYear',
  'value': 'MaxYear'
}, {
  'label': 'terminal',
  'value': 'Terminal'
}, {
  'label': 'location',
  'value': 'Location'
}, {
  'label': 'theme',
  'value': ''
}, {
  'label': 'construction',
  'value': 'Construction'
}, {
  'label': 'asBuilt',
  'value': null
}];
for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
                            Object.keys(valueArray[i]).forEach(function (field) {
                            if(valueArray[i][field] == null){
                            valueArray[i][field] = "";
                            }
                            })                   
                    };
                    console.log(valueArray);
```

Comment: Hope This suits your question

Comment: Can you explain how the code works in the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm looping the whole array and again fetches each object keys. So that instead giving a static key value I'm getting it dynamically. Using this way I'm checking each and every value of an objects.